# What does data-ajax="false" really do?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

The links on my site don't work and I got an solution of using `data-ajax="false"` on my anchors without getting a true explanation. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`data-ajax` is a feature of jQuery Mobile. JQM by default will try to load pages via ajax for improved user experience and transitions. If you set `data-ajax='false'` then JQM will do a normal page request instead of using ajax. This can be used on forms as well as links.

From the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/docs-pages.html):

> This tells the framework to do a full page reload to clear out the Ajax hash in the URL

If you want to disable ajax on all of your links then instead of adding `data-ajax` to everything, you can do it like this:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
```

Comment: I there a way to make all my request "normal"?

Comment: This fixed an issue I had with a plugin not loading sometimes when links were clicked..  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Nothing at all.

[`data-*`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) is a generic set of attributes that you can store data in for access by JavaScript.

Unless you have some JavaScript that deals with them, they are meaningless.

jQuery has nothing built in that does anything with them.

Comment: The thing is that it works. I have a website where i had to change the appereance, to make a responsive design to it. And i found myself with links that don't work

Comment: If "it works" then it is because some JavaScript is doing something with it. The accepted answer assumes you are using jQuery mobile. You never said that in the question.

Answer (score -1):

if you set the attribute of an element to data-name, you can, through jQuery, fetch it using `$('element').data('name')` instead of `$('element').attr('data-name');`, but `data-*` attributes can still be used for event delegation, like `$(document).on('click', '[data-name]', function(){});`