# Jquery Mobile Remove CSS Styling with link tag <A href>

Tags: jquery-mobile

How to remove css Styling from Jquery Mobile 1.45

I use link tag , A href

Try set this  rel="external" data-ajax="false" **data-role="none"** ,but Not working.

`<a href="#" data-role="none">Link ME!</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a basic style, not really a data-role enhancement.

You have to override the css like this [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2yvLy2w1/) :

```
a{
  text-decoration:none!important;
  color:black!important;
  font-weight:normal!important;
}
```

Note : data-ajax=false is more about how the transition is going to happen as someone explained it [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13357149/3974585)

More about data-ajax=false and rel=external on the [**documentation**](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/navigation-linking-pages/#LinkingwithoutAjax)